Can't create a member in a PDS using a JCL
I'm trying to create a member in an existing PDS but it keeps sending this code:
UNIDENTIFIED KEYWORD ON THE DD DUMMY STATEMENT. I'm using this code:
...
//PASO1    EXEC PGM=IEBGENER                               
//SYSUT1   DD   DUMMY,RECFM=FB,LRECL=80                    
//SYSUT2   DD   DSN=MBVT.APPLICBC.PRUEBA4(TEST1),DISP=(SHR)
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*                                   
//SYSIN    DD   DUMMY                                      
//                                                         

I've researched in many pages and they use the same code, also I have seen some youtube videos where they use the code and it works, but I'm testing it and it doesn't work for me. ¿What am I doing wrong?
This is the video in which uses the same code:
Link

The JCL works fine. can you show where you are getting that error? Is it after submission of the job or is it before? JCL checkers might be flagging it but the job will run fine.

It shows after submission, I mean, the log shows the full code and then the message

If it is after submission, then you must have a typo in the job that you showed.  You must have misspelled the LRECL or RECFM ? Can you show the complete the JCL along with "Unidentified keyword" message?

As I can't post the complete code, here is the link

Can you turn HEX ON in your editor, and make sure you aren't passing in any unprintable characters?  Also, why can't you paste in the complete JCL?

Juan,
How are you submitting the job? Is it from the mainframe? or you using any tools like zoau or something?

What level of z/OS are you using?

Or are you using code not obtained from an authorized source, as I sort of suspect based on the userid in the JCL?

I'm submitting it from the mainframe, using the mvs-tk5, the userid is the default one the program had

I'd never heard of MVS-TK5; apparently that is "an implementation of OS/VS2 MVS Release 3.8J," which is 45 years old at this point.  No offense, but you're trying to use documentation and examples for a modern OS and trying to get it running on something that hasn't been supported for decades.  It's similar to trying to get something written in PowerShell running on DOS 3.  It might not be impossible, but it may not work, either.  I'd suggest asking on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Try adding DSORG=PS also given you are running MVS 3.8 you might need to use DCB i.e. //SYSUT1   DD   DUMMY,DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,DSORG=PS)

So, first, since it's a DUMMY statement, there's no real reason to have the other parameters there.  As documented, anything following DUMMY is checked for correctness, but not used.
If you want to keep them, I believe if you just code
//SYSUT1   DD   DUMMY,DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80)

that will work as well.  I'm going to consult with our JCL folks to see why what you're coding isn't working, as I think it should.

yeah, the thing is that I've tried using that way and not putting parameters and in all cases I got errors

In the first one I had the same error and in the second one I got this: IEB317I JOB TERMINATED,NO INPUT BLKSIZE/LRECL

It turns out that the second code created the member, but still gave me that error

Not relevant to the issue at hand, but coding DCB= for LRECL and RECFM etc. is the 'old' way of doing it. Still works, just redundant.

Right.  Well, again, he's using an incredibly old version of OS/370, so . . .

Given is MVS 38j, it is not going to be as forgiving of errors as modern ZOS, try adding DSORG=PS and blksize

If you are running MVS 3.8j, then you need DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=F,BLKSIZE=80).  MVS3.8j is very old and does not support the coding of DCB parameters outside of DCB=().
Since you are coding DUMMY, there is no reason to have the RECFM be blocked, your not going to have more than 1 record and blocking is only a benefit if you have more than one record.

Needs formatting.
